# Can I split a message to different messages and sent to kafka using Camel Kafka Connector

Tags: apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, spring-camel

I am trying to read a file and sent the data to kafka using Camel kafka connectors
Its working but I need to split the file to multiple messages and sent them individually to Kafka

Is it possible to split the data and sent individually to kafka using camel kafka connector
camel-file-kafka-connector is used.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Camel split](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/split-eip.html). This way you can split a message and process them in different ways.